# A column name is 0, and it can not be renamed or selected

Tags: python, pandas

I turned a Series `word` into a dataframe with same name.
After reindexing, I now have the dataframe as such:

```
     index    0
0     a       A
1     b       B
2     c       C
```

and after I renamed the dataframe:

```
words.rename({'index':'word','0':'counts'},axis='columns',inplace=True)
```

it becomes:

```
     word     0
0     a       A
1     b       B
2     c       C
```

As you can see, the column name of 0 remains unchanged.

Then, when I select it,

```
words['0']
```

it shows me this error:

```
KeyError: '0'
```

I tried, it's not alpha bate O, I am sure I did not mix them up....

Pls Help！

ps:codes that I used for creating the Series

```
words=df_new['text'].str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts()
words=pd.DataFrame(words)
words.reset_index(level=0,inplace=True)
```

Comment: Try `0` (the number).

Comment: Maybe it's int "0", did you try that?

Comment: both O, and 0 would not work, and I am pretty sure that is a 0.

Comment: It seems that `0` is not the column name, rather it might be an element in the column. Please provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: the data is too huge to be posted on stackoverflow,the examples are just some represents.

Comment: @Onlyfood - Use `words.rename({'index':'word',0:'counts'},axis='columns',inplace=True)`

Comment: Whatever the column is named, nobody cares. Just rename the axis: `words = words.set_axis(['word', 'counts'], axis=1, inplace=False)`. Who cares what that column name is, just get rid of it -- your error is not all that special indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here DataFrame constructor is not necessary, rather use [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with parameter `name` and for rename `index` add [`Series.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename_axis.html) for avoid default `index` column name:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame({
    'text' : ['A B', 'A C'],

})

print (df_new)
  text
0  A B
1  A C

words=(df_new['text'].str.split(expand=True)
                     .stack()
                     .value_counts()
                     .rename_axis('word')
                     .reset_index(name='counts'))

print (words)
  word  counts
0    A       2
1    B       1
2    C       1
```

Your solution working with rename `0` column - it is integer, not `string` - `'0'`:

```
words=df_new['text'].str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts().reset_index()
words.rename({'index':'word',0:'counts'},axis='columns',inplace=True)

print (words)
  word  counts
0    A       2
1    B       1
2    C       1
```